# How to display featured product in home page using magento?

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I want to add 'featured' attribute set while adding product (dropdown (yes/no)).
On selecting 'yes' the respective products should be shown in home page.
Is it possible ?

Comment: You said that you want to "add [a] featured 'attribute' set", but this is not a suitable approach - you mean that you want to add a "featured" attribute *to* your product attribute sets, correct?

Comment: yeah. I got the solution which i wanted to do .

Comment: There are two way of doing this one is the code by yourself, the process has been defined below, the second it by using a an already developed extensions like - http://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-featured-product-layout.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please go through the below link to show the featured products in Magento Home page.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/84852/

[How Display Featured Products - Magentocommerce](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/4_-_themes_and_template_customization/cms_and_home_page/add_featured_products_to_home_page)

It would be helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks Prakash.The 2nd link is easier and much more accurate.

Comment: Just to mention another solution: If it were for me, i would have created a custom widget (based on existing ones and very simple to adapt).

Comment: What do you say about this extension? http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/featured-products-4605.html Its compatible upto 1.5 but can be used in latest version.

Comment: It was just a try towards doing it programmatically .And got success.However in future will surely use your solutions . Thanks

Comment: Please use more details in your answer. Links are not reliable, and the 2nd link is to a parked domain.

Answer (score 5):

Adding featured products in Magento is very easy. Just follow the steps mentioned below.

->. Log in to your Magento Admin end.

->. Go to Catalog > Manage Categories.

->. Select Root Category of your choice. By default only one Root category is available
    named “Root Catalog”.

->. Now click on Add Subcategory button on left and name new subcategory “Featured” (this 
    name can be anything of your choice).

[image]

->. If you do not want to load category on store front-end then Is Active  to No.

->If you do not want your category to be  appeared in navigation set Include in Navigation 
   Menu to No.

-> After creating the category  you will see the category name and ID on the page title. 
    Note down the ID of your category which is mentioned after ID: label in Category title 
    on page. See the image below for reference.

-> Add few Products in newly created Featured category.

-> Now go to CMS > Pages > Edit Home page > Content.

-> Add following line in the content

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" column_count="4" category_id="5" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

-> This line will create a Magento Block on home page with featured products list

-> Change th category_id="5"  in the block to your own category’s ID

-> Save the page by clicking on Save Page button and go to your home page to see your 
     featured products listing.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! :) It's less cleaner than the attribute way as you have to hardcode the category id (especially if you are using this method on your own bloc) but it's much simpler for the product managers to simply put products on a category.

Comment: Do you know how I can get that block in a phtml file?

Answer (score 0):

follow below tutorial to learn how to Create new "Featured" attribute and show Featured products with the help of

```
<?=$this->getFeaturedProductHtml()?>
```

https://magento2.atlassian.net/wiki/display/m1wiki/How+to+Create+a+Featured+Product